# What causes this triangle effect? (waterfall)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, flow

I was in a friends garden and saw this:

[image]

My question is: what causes the water to flow towards the center? My first thought was that maybe the water in the center falls faster and thus creates a sort of force inwards, but because gravity doesn't care about weight I don't think thats correct...

I also noticed that the width of the water is everywhere the same, exept for the edges. The water which flows towards the center forms a small tube there.

What causes this effect? Or is it simply because of the design of this fountain? (I don't think so, I've seen this before on other designs)

Comment: Probably because of water's surface tension?

Comment: @KunalPawar I believe other fluids behave like that as well.. But I don't really know :D

Comment: If this isn't caused by the design of the fountain (which I suspect it is), then this is almost certainly an effect caused by the surface tension of the water.

Comment: Yes, all fluids have the tendency to minimise their surface area. It takes energy to have a bigger surfav area.

Comment: What's the initial velocity of water at the end of the spout? Isn't it just being squirted towards the centre?

Comment: @innisfree it's difficult to make that out from the picture but it looks like it isn't being thrown towards the centre.

Comment: @innisfree you're right. its not flowing downwards or something like that. the amount of water in the pool just increases and its pushed to the center

Comment: I think that it's simply due to surface tension and the fact that the water moves faster as it falls. Clearly, the water stream can't have a constant cross-sectional area as it falls and gathers increasing speed because the volume of water passing by any point in the stream has to remain constant. So the cross-sectional area has to decrease. In this case of a stream with a long, thin, horizontal cross-section with a large surface area, surface tension causes the stream to contract horizontally as it falls.

Comment: Why is it not Bernoulies principle as an answer which was deleted said? This seems pretty logic to me

Comment: I would rather say that it is caused by the adhesion of the water with the surface.

Comment: A stream from a standard water faucet will exhibit this phenomenon as well, as a 3D cone shape than rather than the "2D triangle" this fountain produces.

Comment: In my judgment, surface tension has very little to do with this behavior.  The fluid is being stretched in the direction of flow, and this would tend to induce transverse tensile stresses.  But, since the sheet of fluid is unconstrained laterally, it must contract in the transverse direction.  Surface tension effects are not strong enough on the length- and time scale to this system to have much additional effect.  To test this, a surface tension reducing agent could be introduced into the water, and the flow re-established.  I contend that no significant change would be observed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is conservation of [mass flow rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_flow_rate). 
Let's imagine to cut the water flow with an imaginary surface: since mass must be conserved, the quantity of mass passing through this surface per unit time must be a constant:

$$\dot m = \rho \ u \ A =  const$$

where $\rho$ is density, $u$ is the velocity of water and $A$ is the cross section of the water flow.

The density is constant in this situation (1). Moreover, let's assume that the thickness of the water flow is almost constant (it looks like it is, up to a good approximation). We will then have

$$A = const \cdot l$$

where $l$ is the width of the water flow. Therefore

$$u \cdot l = const \rightarrow l = \frac{const}{u}$$

Let's take a $z$ axis to start at the top of the fountain (when the water starts to fall) and to finish when the flow enters in the water; it is then easy to see from conservation of energy that

$$u (z) = \sqrt{2 g z}$$

so that

$$l(z) = \frac{const}{\sqrt z}$$

(yes, we are assuming that $g$ is also constant: quite reasonable in this case!)

Of course, this formula cannot be completely right, because it would give you a divergence in $z=0$. We are probably neglecting some other kind of energy (I am betting on surface tension), and the "true" form must probably be something like

$$l(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt {a z + b}} \ \text{cm}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants. You can already see by plotting the function $1/\sqrt{z+1}$ that the shape looks similar to the one in the picture.

So, in conclusion, my opinion is that the shape of the water flow is not that a triangle, but rather that it behaves as $\sim 1/\sqrt z$.

(1) As a matter of fact, the density of water is almost always constant, since water is with very good approximation an *incompressible fluid*.

Comment: Thank you for you're answer. I think that's quite logical

Comment: Dang, when I read this question I was pretty sure it had something to do with conservation of mass/flow rate.  I never thought to try and derive the stream width as a function of height.  Great answer and great catch on the inverse square root relationship.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to the effects on the edges, by the looks of it, it is quite reasonable to think of Kelvin-Helmholtz instabilities, since there will be a shear layer between the water falling at a specific speed and the air being pulled down at a different (probably slower) speed.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.